# Show that $ \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod p.$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

J. Neukirch Book (Algebraic Number Theory), page $50$

It has been mentioned that,

The Legendre symbol $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)=+1 \ \text{or} \ -1$ according as $x^2 \equiv a \mod p$ has solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$ or has not solution. The symbol is multiplicative, $$ \left( \frac{ab}{p} \right)=\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)\left( \frac{b}{p} \right).$$
This is because the group $\mathbb{F}^{*}$ is cyclic of order $p-1$ and the subgroup $\mathbb{F}_p^{{*}^2}$ of squares has index $2$, i.e., $\mathbb{F}_p^*/\mathbb{F}_p^{{*}^2} \cong \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z.$

Since $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)=1 \Leftrightarrow  \bar a \in \mathbb{F}_p^{{*}^2}$, on has also $$ \left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \mod p.$$

**My question-**

How the last relation follows ?

Can you please explain it?

Comment: Look up "Euler's criterion"

Comment: @Wojowu, yes thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\equiv x^2 \mod p$ then $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)=1$ and $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv x^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$.

You know that precisely half the elements are squares and also (because the group is cyclic of even order) half the elements have order dividing $\frac {p-1}{2}$. So the elements which are not squares satisfy $\left( \frac{a}{p} \right)=-1$ and $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1\mod p$.